# Estou de esperanças. Estou grávida?

Tags: etimologia, uso-de-palavras, diferenças-transatlânticas, expressões-idiomáticas

Eu estive a ver [um vídeo no youtube dos barbixas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NkTw7caYpo), um espetáculo de comédia com participantes brasileiros. No [minuto 1:32](https://youtu.be/0NkTw7caYpo?t=1m32s) ele diz "eu estou de esperanças".

Em pt-pt isto é uma outra forma de dizer que a pessoa está grávida. Mas parece que o público começou-se a rir, eventualmente por não ter percebido, ou por ter outro significado.

Qual é o significado de "estou de esperanças" em pt-br? Qual é a origem da expressão "estar de esperanças" em pt-pt?

Comment: Não queres pôr um link?

Comment: Gostava de ver o vídeo, mas de uma maneira geral parece-me mais provável uma audiência rir porque (1) já conhecia a expressão mas acha-a antiquada ou coisa que um 'brasileiro normal' não diria naquelas circunstâncias ou (2) não conhecia, compreendeu pelo contexto, e achou piada.

Comment: @Jacinto Adicionei o famoso video :)

Comment: Eh pá, eu acho que eles se riem da cena, não especialmente do "de esperanças".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O único significado de ***estar de esperanças*** ou ***andar de esperanças*** que encontrei quer no Brasil quer em Portugal é ‘estar grávida’. A expressão vem no dicionário brasileiro [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=esperan%C3%A7a). Agora, pelo que vi na net, a expressão parece ser atualmente relativamente rara no Brasil. Encontram-se alguns exemplos, como [neste artigo no Jornal da Manhã (2016)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=F44DAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA262&dq=%22estava%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1up_DrbzRAhVDxxQKHdvEC4oQ6AEIaDAK#v=onepage&q=%22estava%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&f=false), ou [neste blog](http://www.fotosantesedepois.com/desenvolvimento-do-bebe-6-semanas-de-gestacao/), mas poucos. Mesmo em Portugal é muito mais comum dizer-se que a mulher está grávida.

Só consegui encontrar a expressão a partir do século XIX. Entre o Google Books e o [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/x.asp) encontrei uma meia dúzia de ocorrências no século XIX. Mas dado que nos séculos anteriores existe muito menos material escrito, a expressão poderiam muito bem já ser usada antes, e não aparecer na literatura disponível na net. O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei aparece na [Gazeta de Lisboa de 4 de Março de 1820](https://books.google.pt/books?id=O_0vAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP233&dq=%22est%C3%A1%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW6NOB6IDqAhVvDWMBHVn4D_QQ6AEItgEwDg#v=onepage&q=%22est%C3%A1%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&f=false) (grafia original, negrito meu):

> Posto que a Princeza ao chegar a *S. Cloud* hia com febre, e sobrevindo-lhe delirio, melhorou com tudo, e felizmente não consta que tenha sofrido abalo interior que transtorne o fructo de que **está de esperanças**.

Depois temos um exmplo do do autor brasileiro Álvares de Azevedo (1831-52), em a [*Noite na Taverna*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WrBIBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%22j%C3%A1%20n%C3%A3o%20o%20posso,%20estou%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&source=bl&ots=80st8yl61W&sig=i7ZXjNcdDLeA3uiyuvoKEXZSrbg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuyurb3LzRAhXL8RQKHZJWC5AQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22j%C3%A1%20n%C3%A3o%20o%20posso%2C%20estou%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&f=false), publicado postumamente em 1855:

> —Gennaro, estou desonrada para sempre.. A princípio eu quis-me iludir, já não o posso, **estou de esperanças**...
>   Um raio que me caísse aos pés não me assustaria tanto.
>   —E preciso que cases comigo, que me peças a meu pai, ouves, Gennaro?

Depois vamos encontrando vários exemplos: em [1859 no *Quadro Elementar das Relações Politicas e Diplomaticas de Portugal*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5yv96gg4-ZQC&pg=PA262&dq=%22que%20ella%20estava%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDlvXfg4HqAhUjAGMBHTueDhgQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22que%20ella%20estava%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&f=false) do Visconde de Santarém,  [na peça *O Rio de Janeiro de 1877* (1878)](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22consola%20%C3%A9%20que%20estou%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&oq=%22consola%20%C3%A9%20que%20estou%20de%20esperan%C3%A7as%22&gs_l=serp.3...3483.5944.0.6521.2.2.0.0.0.0.81.153.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.O8j50IKVBZo) do autor brasileiro Artur de Azevedo, [nesta crónica de 1893](http://www.cronicas.uerj.br/home/cronicas/machado/rio_de_janeiro/ano1893/12mar1893.html) de Machado de Assis, e ainda no Aves & Companhia de Eça de Queiroz (anterior à sua morte em 1900, mas de 1925). Nada disto esclarece como se formou a expressão. Mas também não me parece isso misterioso: a mulher que espera um filho, especialmente se o deseja, está de esperanças.

Comment: Em pt-BR pode-se dizer que "Ela está esperando um filho / uma criança / um bebê". Estar de esperanças não será entendido.